# Angular update object in array

Tags: angularjs

I wanna update an object within an objects array. Is there another possibility than iterating over all items and update the one which is matching? Current code looks like the following:

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.object = {
        name: 'test',
        objects: [
            {id: 1, name: 'test1'},
            {id: 2, name: 'test2'}
        ]
    };

    $scope.update = function(id, data) {
        var objects = $scope.object.objects;

        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            if (objects[i].id === id) {
                objects[i] = data;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What does the view look like? If you have a reference to the object where you're calling `update()`, pass in the object instead of the id.

Comment: adding to anthony's suggestion.. `ng-click="update(obj, data)"` instead of `ng-click="update(obj.id, data)"`

Comment: Also, do you want to check the id before adding? I believe, that is not needed in your case?

Comment: @DominikBarann  added the answer.

Comment: @Dominik consider accepting an answer!

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to do that. Your situation is not very clear.

-> You can pass index instead of id. Then, your update function will be like:

```
$scope.update = function(index, data) {
    $scope.object.objects[index] = data;
};
```

-> You can use ng-repeat on your view and bind object properties to input elements.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in object.objects">
    ID: <input ng-model="item.id" /> <br/>
    Name: <input ng-model="item.name" /> <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Added a plunker below

Comment: If you are trying to update by id, then index does not necessarily correspond to id.  You can end up with the wrong record.

Answer (score 7):

Filters that help in finding the element from the array, can also be used to update the element in the array directly.
In the code below [0] --> is the object accessed directly.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/oOaaSQBchSktedkMRUOX?p=preview)

`$filter('filter')($scope.model, {firstName: selected})[0]`

Answer (score 6):

Pass the item to your update method. Take a look at sample bellow.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = 
    [
      {name: 'obj1', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj1', show: true}},
      {name: 'obj2', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj2', show: false}},
    ];
  $scope.updateName = function(item, newName){
     item.name = newName;
  } 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
  <table ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in items">
        <td> {{ x.name }}</td>
        <td> 
           <a href="#" ng-show="!showUpdate" ng-click="someNewName = x.name; showUpdate = true">Update</a>
           <div ng-show="showUpdate" ><input type="text" ng-model="someNewName"> <input type="button" value="update" ng-click="updateName(x, someNewName); showUpdate = false;"></div>
         </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Going off your plunker, I would do this:

- Change

  ```
  <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="selectSubObject(subObject.id)">Edit</a>
  ```

  to be

  ```
  <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="selectSubObject($index)">Edit</a>
  ```
- Then use the array index within your `$scope.selectSubObject` method to directly access your desired element. Something like this:

  ```js
  $scope.selectSubObject = function(idx) {
    $scope.selectedSubObject = angular.copy(
      $scope.selectedMainObject.subObjects[idx]
    );
  };
  ```

If however, you only have the `id` to go off of, then you can use the angular filterService to filter on the `id` that you want. But this will still do a loop and iterate over the array in the background.

See [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) documentation for [ngrepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to see the variables that it exposes.

Comment: Note that angular.copy will create a new object so you won't get the 2-way binding that angular is really useful for.  If you he's plain to update the main object with his changes, then I don't think the angular.copy is necessary.

Comment: Yes it's better to use the index here instead of the id, but the problem is still the same. I have to update the object in my main object and dont know really how to do that, because i dont know the index. I use the copy method because the user should can go back without saving the changes. If i refer to the real object any changes will be saved without pressing the save button. My problem is the save method of my SubObjectController. Added a fork http://plnkr.co/edit/YcPMe0uFWFNgDpZddjt6?p=preview

Comment: If the objective is to NOT loop over the array and you do not have the index then that is not possible. As I mentioned before, you can use the angular [$filter service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to filter your array, but this does a loop under the covers. Example of using the $filter service: `$filter('filter')($scope.selectedMainObject.subObjects, {id: $scope.selectedSubObject.id)`. Another option (what I would do) is to redesign the implementation to save off the index. I've updated your plunker to save of the index: http://plnkr.co/edit/5udyU3o1AR5z5dP1ReFJ?p=preview