# How to bind element with ng-model from an object array key

Tags: arrays, angularjs

This is the scenario

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('bookCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.book = {
        name: 'Session Invites',
        friends: [
             {'id': 1, 'name': 'raju' },
            {'id': 2, 'name': 'radha' },
            {'id': 3, 'name': 'luttappi' },
            ]
    };
    $scope.update = function(){ 
        $scope.book.friends[1] = {'id': 2, 'name': 'sam' };
        alert($scope.book.friends[1].name );
    };
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="bookCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="book.friends[1].name"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="update" ng-click="update()"/>
</div>
```

I would like to use "id" instead of array "index". [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4mh979u/)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="book.friends[1].name"/>
```

Comment: you can use angular.forEach to iterate and then match the id after iterating the array

Comment: @Anita - i would like to bind the array element directly using ng-model, will that be possible?

Comment: I dont think that its possible.

Comment: Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZFm6/)

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741166/angular-update-object-in-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be possible with a `for loop` but, I think this work around below maybe interesting for you.

Just change the structure of your JSON, using `Object.proerty` instead of an array. It will do the tricks.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('bookCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.book = {
        name: 'Session Invites',
        friends: {
            id1: {'name': 'raju' },
            id2: {'name': 'radha' },
            id3: {'name': 'luttappi' },
        }
    };
    $scope.update = function(){ 
        $scope.book.friends.id1 = {'name': 'sam' };
        alert($scope.book.id1.name );
    };
});
```

*NOTE:*
There's a concern about this workaround is the API providing the `JSON`. If the data recived structure fixed and angular need to convert `JSON` to this structure. You might need to aware of how huge is it the `data` that going to be converted. Because such task like this will cause `Memory Leaked`  then `JavaScript Garbage Collection`. And it will slow down your app significantly

Comment: this seems to be a good approach. friends list is a dynamic one, let me see how to load that in this format.

Comment: @CoderHawk Yeap, there're only concern about this workaround is the API providing the `JSON`. If the data recived structure fixed and angular need to convert `JSON` to this structure. You might need to aware of how huge is it the `data` that going to be converted. Because such task like this will cause `Memory Leaked`  then `JavaScript Garbage Collection`. And it will slow down your app significantly. EDIT: I will update this in the answer for the future use.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in this way:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('bookCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.book = {
        name: 'Session Invites',
        friends: [{
            'id': 1,
                'name': 'raju'
        }, {
            'id': 2,
                'name': 'radha'
        }, {
            'id': 3,
                'name': 'luttappi'
        }]
    };
    $scope.update = function (friend) {

        alert(friend.name);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="bookCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="friend in book.friends">
      <input type="text" ng-model="friend.name" />
      <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="update" ng-click="update(friend)" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i would like to avoid ng-repeat since textboxes will be placed in different locations in the form, it is not going to be a list.

Comment: How to submit all values with single save button?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this instead:

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('bookCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.GetOne={};
        $scope.book = {
            name: 'Session Invites',
            friends: [
                 {'id': 1, 'name': 'raju' },
                {'id': 2, 'name': 'radha' },
                {'id': 3, 'name': 'luttappi' },
                ]
        };
        $scope.update = function(){ 
            $scope.GetOne=$scope.book.friends[1];
            alert($scope.GetOne.name );
        };
    });

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="bookCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="GetOne.name" />
      <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="update" ng-click="update()" />
    </div>
  </div>
```