# How to update object in array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I'm building a dashboard using AngularJS + SocketIO and Controller As vm syntax.

I want to update my view when a specific IO message got receive:

```
var vm = this;
vm.products = ProductService.query(); //Get an array of Products

//When receiving an update through SocketIO, update the view
SocketService.on('product:update', function(updated_product) {
    var found = $filter('filter')(vm.products, {_id: updated_product._id}, true);
    if(found.length) { //Product was found, updating product
        $filter('filter')(vm.products, {_id: updated_product._id}, true)[0] = updated_product;
    } else vm.products.push(updated_product); //else add a new product
});
```

I tried adding a `$scope.$apply();` after the update but had the "$apply already in progress" error.

Here is another example with a fork of a Plunker answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30239882/5577145):
[Original with $scope](http://plnkr.co/edit/oOaaSQBchSktedkMRUOX?p=preview)
[Mine with Controller As](http://plnkr.co/edit/MLb57Ef8Oc7kiscoa6PT?p=preview)

What can I do to update the object found by $filter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to replace it in the original collection, not in the filtered.

```
var found = $filter('filter')(vm.products, {_id: updated_product._id}, true);
if(found.length) { //Product was found, updating product
    // found[0] = updated_product;
    vm.products[vm.products.indexOf(found[0])] = updated_product;
} else vm.products.push(updated_product); //else add a new product
```

Other method:

```
var index = vm.products.map(function(v){return v._id}).indexOf(updated_product._id);
vm.products[~index?index:vm.products.length] = updated_product;
```